# OpenGL lighting not acting on some shapes

Tags: opengl, lighting

I'm trying two methods to make a cube. The thing is, if I draw the cube manually, the lighting does not show. I'm a beginner so this might be trivial but I'm at a loss. What shows in my window is this:

[image]

The cube which does show shades is the one I made with GLUT, the other two I made manually by drawing each face. Here is my display method:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable) {
            GL2 gl2 = glautodrawable.getGL().getGL2();
            gl2.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl2.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
                //              gl2.glLoadIdentity();
            gl2.glPushMatrix();

            gl2.glTranslatef(2f, -2f, -4f);
            gl2.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, FloatBuffer.wrap(QA_WHITE));
            gl2.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBuffer.wrap(QA_WHITE));
            gl2.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, FloatBuffer.wrap(QA_WHITE));
            gl2.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_SHININESS, FloatBuffer.wrap(new float[]{50f}));

            wallUnit(glautodrawable);
            gl2.glPopMatrix();

            gl2.glPushMatrix();
            gl2.glTranslatef(-2f, -2f, -10f);
            wallUnit(glautodrawable);
            gl2.glPopMatrix();

            gl2.glPushMatrix();
            gl2.glTranslatef(-4.5f, -2.5f, -10f);
            glut.glutSolidCube(2f);
            gl2.glPopMatrix();


            gl2.glFlush();

        }
```

And my wallUnit() method (since this is supposed to be scaled, textured, and become a piece of wall... in case you wondered.)

```
private static void wallUnit(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
    GL2 gl2 = glAutoDrawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl2.glBegin(gl2.GL_QUADS);    

    // Back face
    gl2.glColor3f(1,0,0);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);            
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);           
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);  
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);        

    // Bottom face
    gl2.glColor3f(0,1,0);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);     
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);        

    // Right side
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);          
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);            
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);         
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);         

    // Top face
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);        
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);          
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);          
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, 1.0f);        

    // Left side
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);        
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);          
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);         
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);        

    // Front face
    gl2.glColor3f(1,0,0);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);        
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);         
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1f, 1.0f);        
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, 1.0f);        

    gl2.glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate normals for your quads:

```
gl2.glBegin(gl2.GL_QUADS);    

// Back face
gl2.glColor3f(1,0,0);
gl2.glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // quad normal
gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);            
gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);           
gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);  
gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);

...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I dabbled with openGL.  I think you need to define normals for each side of your cubes.

> OpenGL supports a fixed number of lights.  The number that are available depends on the implementation, but will always be at least 3.  Go to the line after glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); and add the following:
>
> // Enable lighting nullglEnable(GL_LIGHTING); nullglEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
>
> When you compile, you'll discover that this does not really do anything different.  **The light is on, but it's not being used, yet.  The reason is that OpenGL needs to know a "normal" for every vertex it is lighting.**  OpenGL does its lighting computations at the vertices only for efficiency reasons.

https://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse872/tutorial3.html

For example.  The normal (i.e. vector perpendicular to the plane) for the back plane is <0, 0, -1>.

```
// Back face 
gl2.glColor3f(1,0,0);
gl2.glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);
gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);
```

Repeat for the other sides.